# What are alternatives to TensorFlow Serving?

Tags: open-source, machine-learning

TensorFlow is software focused specifically on making easier to train and fit deep belief neural networks. They just released TensorFlow Serving which makes it easy to deploy these models into production.

TensorFlow Serving seems quite amazing:

- low latency inference thanks to GPUs
- horizontally scalable with Kubertenes
- reliable thanks to Google creating it
- provides online, perpetually learning models
- has AB testing

Spark might come come close but it seems like it does not have low latency inference. Spark is focused more on reliably managing general purpose big data machine learning and ETL tasks for both batch and stream. It seems like it has not yet focused on low latency inference model predictions (instead focusing on high throughput).

(Apologies if this seems like I'm just praising TensorFlow or something, I'm actually serious. I'm more of a Spark fan honestly)

Comment: For people that are not familiar with those products, you can include a couple sentences regarding the purpose of the software.

Comment: Added a bit more. Please let me know if that works.